# Piping Several commands in a BASH shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to recursively loop through a directory which contains numerous other directories and files and then find all the .rb files and copy them to another directory.

This is what I have so far but it is not working quite right as it copies everything in the current directory to the specified directory and does not only print .rb (ruby) files to the directory from the directory that is recursively iterated through.

This is the BASH command I am using: `ls -R metasploit-framework-master | grep .rb | cp * gems`

In this command `metasploit-framework-master` is the top-level directory to recursively iterate through with the `ls -R` command. Also `gems` is the directory to place all the .rb ruby files in.

The first part `ls -R metasploit-framework-master | grep .rb` does seem to find all the ruby script source files but the last part `grep .rb | cp * gems` does not seem to pipe in the output of the grep command to the copy command.

Can any BASH experts please help me out? 
`

Comment: "cp * gems" does not read from stdin.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @asjo this is not shell programming?

Comment: I wouldn't call piping output from one command into another programming, no - I think this question belongs on another of the sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use find with exec, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find#Execute_an_action . In your case, this should do it:

```
find metasploit-framework-master -name '*.rb' -exec cp -av {} gems \;
```

Comment: I tried this seems to work! :D Thank-you for the help. I am going to experiment with the other guys ideas/script first before voting an official answer. This is awesome though. :D !!!

Comment: what is the backslash at the end doing? or the brackets for that matter? 0_o

Comment: @user3808269 [`man find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and also [tons of good examples, `-exec` specifically](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux%20find%20exec%20example).

Comment: @JasonC thanx for the helpful info I will have to check these out. :D

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to drop in here is `xargs`.  `xargs` lets you take `stdin` and use them as arguments in other commands.  I would try something like this:

```
## This will not work as expected ## 
$ ls -R metasploit-framework-master | grep .rb | xargs -I{} cp {} gems
```

However, this really won't work as you want:

- `ls -R` is not going to give you the full path.
- `grep .rb` will match more than just that end with `.rb` and should be escaped.
- `cp {} gems` will not handle spaces in the path.

The better way to do this is to use `find`.

```
$ find metasploit-framework-master -name '*.rb' | xargs -I{} cp {} gems/
```

will let you do the recursive enumeration you want.  From there you can pipe that to `xargs`, or even more succinct use the `-exec` flag:

```
$ find metasploit-framework-master -name '*.rb' -exec cp {} gems/ \;
```

Comment: `ls -R` does not output the file path, this is not going to work.

Comment: @Michael Thanks, for the helpful reply. What is the brackets doing in this command (The last one) that follow the -r (recursive copy)? Also what is the backslash doing at the end and is the semi-colon actually necessary?

Comment: The brackets are a placeholder for where you want to fill in the argument and the \ is necessary to escape the semi-colon from the rest of the command.

Comment: Your `ls` answer is flawed in many ways. Beyond the point made above by @Jakob, `grep .rb` will match such filenames as “carbon” and “orbital”, because the “`.`” isn’t escaped and the regular expression isn’t anchored with a “`$`”. Also, `find … | xargs …` has a problem with filenames that contain whitespace and/or quotes; use `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …` instead. Also, why did you change `cp` to `cp -r`?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes use teh "xargs".  I see people using find with exec.  I still prefer using xargs. Also, when you do this, please use the "echo" command first whenever possible so you can see what will actually happen before it happens.  I have started using for loops instead of pipe and xargs because it gives me a lot more control over using "echo" to see what's going to happen.  A simple example would be like "for file in `[your find statement]`; do echo "cp $file gems/"; done"  and then if you like what you see, take out the echo and then run it.

Comment: @Scott - yeah, those are good points.  Part of why I left the first bad example was to inform of potential pitfalls on the way.  But the formatting is pretty poor for this purpose.